# remove non-numerical characters in string with jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to remove all non-numerical characters inside my dl container except the element with the id #headercartsum

How do i do this with jquery? I manage to straight remove or replace the text, but when it comes to filter it, thats a bit to tricky for me.

My HTML:

```
<dl>
 <dt><span>items: <em class="minicart"></em><em id="headercartqty">4 items</em></span><span><em id="headercartsum">€1,375</em></span></dt>
 <dd></dd>
</dl>
```

Update:

I tried this which fixes one part of the question:

```
$('em#headercartqty').text(function(_,xText){
return xText.replace(/[^\d]/g, ''); 
})
```

the problem is the text between the span element: items: because how the html setup i cant use the above code to target the span class.. So whats the next step here?

Comment: Please share [what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com). "giv me teh codez" style questions are not useful to future readers.

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: what will the html look like once you are successful?

Comment: The same? I just want to remove the non-numerichal string - the HTML will be the same.

Comment: If you want to remove something, it will not look the same.  Provide a sample that is exactly what it should look like.

Comment: For example...

<dl><dt><span><em class="minicart"></em><em id="headercartqty">4</em></span><span><em id="headercartsum">1375</em></span></dt>
 <dd></dd>
</dl>

this is what your html would look like if you removed all non-numeric characters that are not explicitly tags or attributes.

Comment: yeah thats true- didn't reflect the strings as HTML. Thats exactly how i want it. @whipdancer

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in the element itself staying on the site you can remove everything except the element like this:

```js
var headercartsum = $("#headercartsum");
$("dl").empty().append(headercartsum);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>JS Bin</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <dl>
            <dt><span>items: <em class="minicart"></em><em id="headercartqty">4 items</em></span><span><em id="headercartsum">€1,375</em></span></dt>
            <dd></dd>
        </dl>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: could you describe what result you want? like "before -> after"

Comment: I want to remove the text "items" and "items:" not based on the actually words - but them being a non-numerical.